# Función que retorna un struct

Tags: c++

soy estudiante de programación de primer año. Estoy estudiando para los exámenes y me encontré con este problema:

> Una empresa que comercializa repuestos de automóviles tiene 14 sucursales en el país. Se desea analizar el desempeño de la empresa en el mes de abril de 2022 (30 días). Escriba un programa C++ que  primeramente lea código, nombre y localidad de cada sucursal. Una vez finalizada esa carga que ingrese por cada venta 3 datos: código sucursal (1..14), día (1..30) y monto en pesos.
>
> Puede haber más de una venta en el mismo día y de la misma sucursal. Los datos de las ventas se deben cargar hasta que el usuario ingrese un código de sucursal igual a 0. El programa debe obtener e informar:
>
> 1. Mediante una función: retornar un struct con el nombre y localidad
>    de la sucursal que logró el mayor monto de ventas en todo el mes, y
>    dicho monto;
> 2. Mediante una función: cuántas sucursales no tuvieron
>    ventas en el día 10;
> 3. el monto recaudado por la empresa por ventas
>    en el día 15.

La principal duda que tengo es con el inciso 1, no se a que se refiere con una función que retorne un struct ni como resolverlo. Si alguien podría aclararme esa duda y mostrarme como resolverlo estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Pongamole de nombre al `struct` `A`. Tu funcion seria algo como `A mayor_monto(parametros...)`. Dentro de la funcion retornas como retornarias cualquier otra variable.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos una estructura de datos:

```
struct Sucursal
{
    std::string nombre;
    std::string localidad;
    double monto;
};
```

Ahora te dicen que devuelvas un `struct`, es decir, quieren que implementes una función cuyo tipo de retorno sea una estructura como ésta.

```
Sucursal sucursal_con_mayor_monto() {
    // ...
}
```

¿Y de dónde obtienes los datos a devolver? Bueno, ya te están diciendo en el enunciado que tu programa maneja una lista de objetos:

> Escriba un programa C++ que primeramente lea código, nombre y localidad de cada sucursal

Luego en alguna parte de tu código tendrás que crear dicha lista:

```
std::vector<Sucursal> lista_sucursales;
```

Ahora, lo que tiene que hacer esta función es recorrer esta lista para localizar el objeto con mayor monto y devolver dicho objeto:

```
Sucursal to_return;

for(const & sucursal : lista_sucursales)
{
    if (/* condicion para buscar la sucursal con mayor monto */)
        to_return = sucursal;
}

return to_return;
```